# Why there are no bijective datatypes

Tags: types, dictionary, mapping, bijection

I recently ran into a situation where I needed to add reverse lookup functionalities in my mappings, and then I was surprised by the fact there there are simply no datatypes designed for this kind of bijection.

I was able to get around using two maps, one key-value, one value-key

but I am really really curious about why there are no bijective datatypes

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: its general, I can't find any bijective types in static typing languages such as C++, Java, C#, as for Js, python and etc it's really meaningless

Comment: Well, C++ has [`boost::bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) for example.

Comment: as much as I know it relies on 2 unidirection maps

Comment: Well, how else would you implement it?

Comment: that is my question, why there are no native implementations of bijective datatypes, is it because there are no efficient algorithms or what..

Comment: One way to look at it is that you need to be able to do lookups on `x` or lookups on `y`.  Therefore, you need two lookup mechanisms (i.e. two hashtables or whataver).  Theoretically you could do it all with one merged hashtable, but I don't know whether that offers any advantage in practice.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth make it an answer.